# Graphic interface with Arch ARM/Debian on RPI

Tags: debian, archlinux, gui

I am a student and my laptop just broke. Due to my lack of money I am thinking to buy a RPI. What I wonder is how well a graphical interface would run on RPI if I install Arch Arm or Debian.

The things I would like to do:

- read pdf docs(preferably adobe reader);
- browse with a graphical browser(firefox);

It is possible to do this? What I should I use (e.g. gnome, kde)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Adobe reader but there are some other alternatives that work well. Speaking about browsing, that can be done too.

But you have to be aware of some facts: Raspi is only board, you will need monitor, mouse, keyboard, etc. And Raspi is only 700MHz single core, so don't expect to watch Youtube and prepare for super-slow scrolling.

If I was you, I would look to buy used laptop that still works. And save some money for Raspi to learn programming and become rich with that :)